# Does the debian-installer install packages from remote repositories?

Tags: 10.04, debian-installer

I am installing Lucid server from an ISO image. Could the debian-installer that come along that distribution install packages fetched from remote repositories during the install of a new system?

If that is the case, is there anyway to disable this behavior? I am trying to create a stable system image, and one source of noise I want to avoid is updated packages.

Answer (score 1):

The only package updates to lucid now are critical updates, security updates, and similar. You want these packages, or you could easily end up with a vulnerable system.

There is very little "package churn" in Lucid apart from this though. If you install from an ISO then update to the latest lucid packages just once after install, you probably won't see more than a couple of new updates a month [1].

[1] wild guess in the dark but I'd be surprised if it was above this ballpark.